# What is the difference between "To finish something" and "To end something"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "To finish something" and "To end something"
When do people say end and when do people say finish ?

Comment: Have you tried searching ["end vs finish"](https://www.google.com/search?q=end+vs+finish) on Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To finish means that something is completed.  To end means to stop doing something; finish is not implied with end.

In my opinion "We finished the project." and "We ended the project" mean two different things, however I am sure some would argue that in current usage the two sentences are interchangeable...not for me.

Comment: Yes, *finish* implies completion. However *end* as a verb does have senses which are beyond the scope of *finish*, and the entire situation is not straightforward. You could for example say *William Wilberforce deserves much credit for the ***ending* of slavery*** (One would not use *finish* in that sense) *Finish* has a more active and doing sense, whilst *ending* can simply imply ceasing.